# Mongo: Create unique text index

Tags: mongodb

Trying to make an index in Mongo that requires the key to be unique and the value to be a text field type.

I create the index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({id: 'text'}, {unique: true})`
```

I insert my first record:

```
db.collection.insert({id: '1'})
```

I insert a second record with id of 1 (an integer) and expect an error (something like: "id cannot be integer!")

```
db.collection.insert({id: 1})
```

How do I ensure that only strings are allowed in the "id" field and that an error is thrown when someone tries to insert an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool to ensure correct data types are inserted is [SchemaValidation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/).

In your particular case it must be something like this:

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "collection",
   validator: { $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [ "id" ],
      properties: {
         id: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         }
      }
   } }
} )
```